# How can I select nested element in different tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, jquery-selectors, selector

I want to take text data in span tags.(1 and 2).I have to choose separately.How can I do?

```
<a>
<tr data-range="one">
       <td class="font-array">
            <span>1</span>
       </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-range="one">
      <td class="font-array">
            <span>2</span>
       </td>
    </tr>
</a>
```

Comment: Please provide more specific details on what you are trying to accomplish and format for final output. See [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
let texts = [];
document.querySelectorAll('[data-range=one] .font-array span').forEach(item=>texts.push(item.innerText));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 